# Unir mesas em AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, node.js

Estou precisando muito uma ajuda do conhecimento de vocês. Atualmente estou desenvolvendo um *web app* para um restaurante com vários módulos.

No módulo da caixa, em um `<div>` estão exibindo-se os pedidos que estão em aberto como amostram os códigos abaixo.

Agora o que eu preciso é que em vez de mostrar cada `orderOpen` separadamente, as ordens que são com o mesmo `Order.board` estejam em um só. Unir todas as ordens que compartilhem um mesmo número de mesa.

**Order.js**

```
 $scope.orderFindOpen = function(  ) {
    Order.orderFindOpen(function(result){
        console.log("pedido em aberto");
        console.log(result.orders);
        $scope.ordersOpen = result.orders;
        $scope.ordersOpen.forEach(function(order, $index){
            $scope.ordersOpen[$index].board = Order.board({id: order.id});
            $scope.ordersOpen[$index].payment = PAY[order.payment].dsca;
        });
  });
}
```

**box.html**

```
<div class="container12">
    <div class="cls89 a_icon" ng-repeat="order in ordersOpen" ng-click="selectedOrder(order)" >
        <span class="cls06 cls08"></span>
        <img src="../../images/ico-mesa.png" alt="Norway" class="cls90" >
        <label class="cls85 cls86">{{ order.board.number }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```